# How to pass container ip as ENV to other container in docker-compose file

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
 app-web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  environment:
    PG_HOST: $(APP_DB_IP)
    PG_PORT: 5432
  ports:
   - "8081:8080"
  links: 
   - app-db

 app-db:
  build: ./db
  expose: 
   - "5432"

  volumes:
   - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I want to pass to app-web the ip of app-db (Postgresql in this case) as ENV var so it can connect to the DB smoothly... any idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 11):

You actually don't need to do any of this, since you're already using the `links` feature in Docker Compose. Just get rid of the `PG_HOST` variable and use the `app-db` hostname:

```
services:
 app-web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  environment:
    PG_PORT: 5432
  ports:
   - "8081:8080"
  links: 
   - app-db
```

Since you included the `app-db` entry under `links`, you can simply use `app-db` as a hostname in your `app-web` container. Docker will set up a hostname mapping in the `app-web` container that resolves the `app-db` hostname to the database container's IP address.

You can verify that by running the following, which will try to ping the `app-db` container from the `app-web` container:

```
docker-compose exec app-web bash -c "ping app-db"
```

This should show output from the ping command showing the resolved IP address of the `app-db` container, for example like this:

```
PING app-db (172.19.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
```

Press `ctrl+c` to stop the ping command.

Like shown in the other answer, if you still want to pass in the hostname (which is probably a good idea, just in case you ever want to point to a different database), you can just use `app-db` as a value:

```
services:
 app-web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  environment:
    PG_HOST: app-db
    PG_PORT: 5432
  ports:
   - "8081:8080"
  links: 
   - app-db
```

Comment: Without the [deprecated docker links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/), when using two containers on the same bridge network through compose, the 'just use the service name' @nwinkler suggests still applies.

Answer (score 10):

You can use app-db as name instead of ip, docker will automatically determine what the right ip. As stated in the Docker docs: A container can always discover other containers on the same stack using just the container name as hostname.

So in your example you can use:

```
environment:
    PG_HOST: app-db
```

Source:https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/#discovering-containers-on-the-same-service-or-stack